# Pattern Printing

Tags: java

I like to print a pattern in java which gives the output:

```
1
23
456
78910  ....
```

But i am not getting how to do this, I wrote a program to print pattern of

```
1
12
123
1234 ...
```

as

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int r,c;
for(r=1;r<=5;r++) {
        for(c=1;c<=r;c++){
        System.out.print(c+" ");
    }

    System.out.println();   
}}}
```

Getting that last number on each row and start from that number on the second row is what I am having trouble with. I tried adding an another for loop in between the other but it didn't help.Can anyone get me what I am missing and how to do this!

Comment: You need an additoinal counter variable thats independend from the loop variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the column counter `c`, which is reset at every row: you'll want a separate variable to hold the number you want to print.

Also, you should probably start getting accustomed to start counting at zero :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 1;
    for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < r+1; c++) {
            System.out.print(n++);
            if (c != r) System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AkshitKumar nevermind: everyone started as a newbie. Never feel ashamed to ask! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pattern14 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int flag = 1;
        
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {//number of rows
            
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++) { // decides the number of digits in row
                System.out.print(flag+++" ");
            }
            
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for giving an answer. Your answer would be more helpful if you explain why the code you posted works- could you perhaps edit your answer to include that?

Comment: This is the same code as the previous answer except that it prompts for the number of rows (instead of assuming 4.)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int x=1;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();

    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        for (int j=1;j<=i;j++) {
            System.out.print(x+++" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).